# check_box_tag is only passing the last check box value to params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1, form-helpers

I have a form_builder for my `@organization` object where I have inserted a `check_box_tag`:

```
form_for @organization do |f|
  f.text_field :name
  City.all.each do |city|
    check_box_tag(:cities, city.id)
  end
  f.submit
end
```

`City` and `Organization` don't have a relationship.

How should I write the code such as all checked boxes' values are passed to params?

Comment: have you use activeadmin and/or decorators? =)

Comment: Sorry, but cannot see how that would improve my understanding of the `check_box_tag`...

Comment: if you think that we should not know the details, solve the problem by yourself

Comment: Learn more about check_box_tag [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch the cities from the Controller/Model itself:

```
@cities = City.all
```

Then, you could use:

```
  <% @cities.each do |city| %>
    <%= check_box_tag 'city_ids[]', city.id -%>
  <% end %>
```

Refer: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag

Hope it helps :)

Comment: wow GENIUS! the brackets did it. thank you, thank you, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`collection_check_boxes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes).

```
f.collection_check_boxes :city_ids, City.all, :id, :name
```